# swift 濁音がある平仮名並び替え

Tags: ios, swift4

var namae = [こいけ", "ごとう", "こじま"]

という配列を並び替えて　["こいけ",　"こじま",　"ごとう"]　という順にしたいのですが、どうしても　["ごとう", "こいけ", "こじま"]と濁音が最初に来てしまいます。良い方法はないでしょうか。